# the best way to keep quality of the texture

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x

I found that image lost quality in rendering.

GL_LINEAR setting make it smooth, and losing sharpen.
Any way to save its quality?

This this my code:

```
auto tex = TextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("No_1.png");
auto sprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(tex);
```

It's hard to post all code, this is a part of CCTexture2D.cpp in cocos2d-x engine.

```
if (mipmapsNum == 1)
{
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, _antialiasEnabled ? GL_LINEAR : GL_NEAREST);
}else
{
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, _antialiasEnabled ? GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST : GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
}

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, _antialiasEnabled ? GL_LINEAR : GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```

CCTexture2D.cpp link: github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp

cocos2d-x link: github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

screen shot:
[image]
source picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do? You always will get some resampling issues if the sampling frequency doesn't exactly match. YOu can do a pixel-exact drawing which does not change the appearance of the texture in any way, but hat implies the image can't be scaled or rotated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to see the problem with your examples. `GL_LINEAR` is the correct choice for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` (magnification). The best 'standard' interpolation for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

Let's say you have a texture (id) bound with:
`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);`

Now you can specify how texture mapping is interpolated:

```
GLenum target = GL_TEXTURE_2D;

GLint mag_filter = GL_LINEAR;
GLint min_filter = GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR;

glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag_filter);
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min_filter);
```

You might get better results with the 'ubiquitous' extension of anisotropic filtering. But I'd need some more details before spending time on this. With modern (core) OpenGL, you probably want to achieve this with [sampler](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object) objects.

Comment: I set parameters as Texture2D::TexParams texParams = { GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE };  but it still not working.